# Different results for stratified cross validation and train test split for CNN

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, deep-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying to develop an image classifier using conventional neural networks. Now I was looking at evaluating the model using 10-fold cross validation and through repeated train test splitting (hold out partitioning). When I do repeated hold out partitioning, I get an average error of 1.5%, and for stratified cross validation, I get error of more than 10%. Just was wondering how this was happening?

The code is as given below

```
# X is the image feature input which is of size (4571, 91, 91) which represents 4571 images each of size 91x91.
# y is the vector of labels

# Repeated hold out partitioning
y_c = to_categorical(y)
for i in range(10):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_c, test_size=0.1, stratify = y_c)
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, stratify = y_train)

    # reshape to be [samples][pixels][width][height]
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')
    X_val = X_val.reshape(X_val.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')

    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(91, 91, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), epochs=40, batch_size=8, verbose=1)
    # Final evaluation of the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

//

```
# X is the image feature input which is of size (4571, 91, 91) which represents 4571 images each of size 91x91.
# y is the vector of labels

# Stratified cross validation
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42)
skf.get_n_splits(X, y)

print(skf)  
conf_mat = np.zeros(shape=(2,2))

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
#     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y_c[train_index], y_c[test_index]
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=42, stratify = y_train)

    # reshape to be [samples][pixels][width][height]
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')
    X_val = X_val.reshape(X_val.shape[0], 91, 91, 1).astype('float32')

    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(91, 91, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), epochs=40, batch_size=8, verbose=1)
    # Final evaluation of the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

X is the image feature input which is of size (4571, 91, 91) which represents 4571 images each of size 91x91. y is the label vector of size(4571, )

Comment: Is it possible that your data is ordered in some non-random way, e.g. in terms of the label? If you were doing image recognition with 10 classes (e.g. the 10 digits of MNIST), and the data were ordered in terms of the label, then if you did stratified cross-validation and used 10 folds, then the first classifier would train on digits 0-8 and test on 9, the second classifier would train on digits 0 and 2-9 and test on 1 etc. This would be the worst case scenario as it would literally only be testing on the exact digit it hasn't seen before.

Comment: @gazza89 Yes the data is ordered as in this case, the first 35% is of one class and the rest is of the other class. But here splitting is done on a stratified manner, so i guess the order might be not relevant as equal proportions from both classes are included in the train, test and validation sets.